# How can I have a bottom navigation appended not on all the screens in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation

I was trying to implement the navigation between screens. I have the first screen, where the user must insert the invitation code. At this point user is not authorised yet, and I don't want him/her to use the bottom navigation bar.
Here is my implementation of the navigation:

home_view.dart

```
import 'package:fauna/app/styles/colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import 'home_view_model.dart';

class HomeView extends GetView<HomeController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Navigator(
        key: Get.nestedKey(1),
        initialRoute: '/invite-code',
        onGenerateRoute: controller.onGenerateRoute,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Obx(() => BottomNavigationBar(
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  FontAwesomeIcons.baby,
                  color: vaccineValid,
                  size: 15,
                ),
                title: Text('Pet details'),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  FontAwesomeIcons.airbnb,
                  color: vaccineValid,
                  size: 15,
                ),
                title: Text('Vet profile'),
              ),
            ],
            currentIndex: controller.currentIndex.value,
            selectedItemColor: Colors.green,
            onTap: controller.changePage,
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

home_binding.dart

```
import 'package:fauna/app/modules/home/home_view_model.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class HomeBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut(() => HomeController());
  }
}
```

home_controller.dart

```
import 'package:fauna/app/modules/invite_code/invite_code_binding.dart';
import 'package:fauna/app/modules/invite_code/invite_code_view.dart';
import 'package:fauna/app/modules/pet_details/pet_details_binding.dart';
import 'package:fauna/app/modules/pet_details/pet_details_view.dart';
import 'package:fauna/app/modules/vet_profile/vet_profile_binding.dart';
import 'package:fauna/app/modules/vet_profile/vet_profile_view.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class HomeController extends GetxController {
  late BuildContext context;

  static HomeController get to => Get.find();
  var currentIndex = 0.obs;
  final pages = <String>['/pet-details', '/vet-profile'];
  var count = 0.obs;

  void changePage(int index) {
    currentIndex.value = index;
    Get.toNamed(pages[index], id: 1);
  }

  Route? onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    if (settings.name == '/invite-code') {
      return GetPageRoute(
        settings: settings,
        page: () => InviteCodeView(),
        binding: InviteCodeBinding(),
      );
    }

    if (settings.name == '/pet-details') {
      return GetPageRoute(
        settings: settings,
        page: () => PetDetailsView(),
        binding: PetDetailsBinding(),
      );
    }

    if (settings.name == '/vet-profile') {
      return GetPageRoute(
        settings: settings,
        page: () => VetProfileView(),
        binding: VetProfileBinding(),
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to disappear after navigating to any screen when onTap bottom navigation item, you must don't use GetPageRoute vb. Firstly, create 'HostView' and PetDetailsView, VetProfileView pass to body of scaffold. Change dynamically showing index with IndexedStack. So, you navigate to HostView after authenticate user.
I added an example code for you below.

```dart
class HostView extends StatefulWidget {
  const HostView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HostViewState createState() => _HostViewState();
}

class _HostViewState extends State<HostView> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  final _pages =  <Widget>[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _selectedIndex,
        children: _pages,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (int index) => setState(() => _selectedIndex = index),
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            label: 'Pet Details',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by disappear?  What will disappear with my approach?

Comment: If you add a new screen to navigation stack, your bottom navigation bar stay behind up screen. So, you just change scaffold body with IndexedStack or other logics